# error when creating a new pre-rendering process (automaic row fetch)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

so i had a problem with my page and i after i compared it with other similar pages i noticed it's missing a pre-rendering -> after header -> process which basically reloads data automatically with the item value that i sent from the previous page. the process is called automatic row fetch [lefacy].
i tried to create it for that page but it always show an error when i try to load it.
any tips what i might be missing

[image]

[image]

and i get this error message

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 22: PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
Contact your application administrator. Details about this incident are available via debug id "353666".

Technical Info (only visible for developers)
```

```
error_statement:
begin begin  select  into  from "CONTRAT" where "ID_CONTRAT" = :p_rowid; end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your select clause is incomplete. You should inform something on select and into.
example:

```
declare
  v_name varchar2(50);
begin
  select NAME
  into v_name
  from EMPLOYEE;
end;
```